# Excel VBA Changing Combobox list from static range to dynamic

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

This should be pretty simple, but I am struggling.
Right now, this code works:

```
cboCategoryEdit1.List = Sheets(2).Range("A2:A40").Value
```

I am trying to "clean up" my project by changing how the combobox is populated.  I'd like it to be a combobox with a range that only takes populated cells.  Meaning I need to use the last row function.  I changed the code to this and I just get an error of "Method or Data Member Not Found".  Here is my problem code:

```
Dim i As Range
With Sheets("xRef-Categories")
    Set i = .Range("A2:A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End With
Me.cboCategoryEdit1.ListFillRange = i.Address
```

Thanks for any help on this one.

btw:  Sheet2 is "xref-Categories"

Answer (score 0):

You simply need this...

```
With Sheets("xRef-Categories")
    Me.cboCategoryEdit1.List = .Range("A2:A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
End With
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thank you!

Comment: @jpend314 You're welcome! If that takes care of your original question, please take a minute to accept the answer to mark your question as Solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it like this:

```
With Sheets("xRef-Categories")
    Me.cboCategoryEdit1.List = .Range("A2" , .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
End With
```